# Compute a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Fix $\delta >0$. What is the value of the below limit?
$$\lim_{s\downarrow 0}s\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\cdot\frac{e^{-\delta^2/(2t)}}{2\pi t}dt.$$
I believe the limit equals zero, but I do not see a simple way to evaluate the limit. It's important to note that dominated convergence does not apply because $t\mapsto \frac{e^{-\delta^2/(2t)}}{2\pi t}$ is not integrable, and monotone convergence gives $0\cdot \infty$ so we couldn't use it either.

For those curious, this limit comes from Kai Lai Chung and Zhongxin Zhao's *From Brownian Motion to Schrodinger Equation*, page 40.

Comment: $$I(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{e^{-\delta^2/(2t)}}{2\pi t}dt=\frac1\pi\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\delta\sqrt\frac s2(x+1/x)}}xdx$$
$$=\frac1\pi\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\delta\sqrt\frac s2x}}x\left(1-\sqrt\frac s2\frac\delta x+\frac s2\frac{\delta^2}{2x}-...\right)dx$$
$$=-\frac{\ln s}{2\pi}-\frac1\pi\left(\ln\frac\delta{\sqrt2}+\gamma\right)+O(\sqrt s)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, integrate by parts! Here it gives
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} se^{-st}\frac{e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{2\pi t}\, dt &= -e^{-st}\frac{e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{2\pi t} \bigg|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty -e^{-st} \biggl( \frac{\delta ^2 e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{4 \pi  t^3}-\frac{e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{2 \pi  t^2} \biggr) \,dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \biggl( \frac{\delta ^2 e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{4 \pi  t^3}-\frac{e^{-\delta^2/2t}}{2 \pi  t^2} \biggr) \,dt
\end{align*}
(verify the boundary terms vanish),
which now converges absolutely and so dominated convergence is back on the table; the answer is indeed $0$.

(One hint that made me think of integration by parts is that I didn't want that factor of $s$ outside the integral—I just wanted an integral of a function depending nicely on $s$—and that was one way to arrange it.)